# Get JSON Array from JSON Object and Count Number of Objects

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a column that contains some data like this:

```
{
  "activity_goal": 200,
  "members": [
    {
      "json": "data"
    },
    {
      "HAHA": "HAHA"
    },
    {
      "HAHA": "HAHA"
    }
  ],
  "name": "Hunters Team v3",
  "total_activity": "0",
  "revenue_goal": 200,
  "total_active_days": "0",
  "total_raised": 300
}
```

I am using `cast(team_data -> 'members' as jsonb)` to get the "Members" JSON array, which gives me a column like this:

```
[
  {
    "json": "data"
  },
  {
    "HAHA": "HAHA"
  },
  {
    "HAHA": "HAHA"
  }
]
```

I am using `array_length(cast(team_data -> 'members' as jsonb), 1)` to pull a column with the number of Members that exist in the list. When I do this, I am given this error:
`function array_length(jsonb, integer) does not exist`
Note: I have also tried casting as "json" instead of "jsonb"

I am following [this documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`JSON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) functions when working with json such as `json_array_length`

```sql
select json_array_length(team_data -> 'members') from mytable
```